# How can I format the array on a specific format in my laravel controller function?

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, single-page-application

I'm currently creating a laravel vue spa, and just wondering on how can I get designation names with these designation id's with the same structure. This is the json of designation id's:

```html
[
  [
    1,
    5
  ],
  [
    1,
    3
  ]
]
```

This is my `getDesignations` function in `EmployeesController.php`:

```html
    public function getDesignations($id) {
        $employee_designation_ids = Employees::find($id)->pluck('designation_id')->toArray();
        $designation_name = [];
        foreach ($employee_designation_ids as $employee_designation_id) {
            $designation = Designations::where('id', '=', $employee_designation_id); 
            //$designation_name[] =  $designation;
        }

        return $employee_designation_ids;
    }
```

Comment: You need to create json format from array?

Comment: I wanted to format it in array, sorry, but showing the names from another table based on the given id's.

Comment: This is not really the laravel way, i would bet you, there is a more pragmatic approach can you provide example database structure between the two models?

Answer (score 0):

If you want specifically that format, you can do it like this (with a lot of guesses in my part since you did not share your Tables structures)

```
public function getDesignations($id) {
    $employee_designation_ids = Employees::find($id)->designation_id;
    return [[$id, $employee_designation_ids]];
}
```

But why are you returning a double table for a single row result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help! I've managed to fix it with this method in my controller:

```html
public function getDesignations(Request $request, $id) {
        $employee_designation_ids = Employees::where('id', $id)->pluck('designation_id');
        return Designations::whereIn('id', $employee_designation_ids[0])->pluck('name');
    }
```